# Question about Dog and Dog's female

Tags: american-english, word-usage, british-english, offensive-language

I am a non-native speaker trying to learn English. I have a question about an animal.

Why is "dog" considered a good word and while its female equivalent, "bitch", is considered a bad word? In essence both are the same animal just masculine and feminine. I have even seen people calling a "bitch" as dog while they call other animals by their female terms.

Please do not get me wrong I am just trying to understand why there is so much differentiation between male and female versions of the same animal?

Comment: _Bitch_ is only a 'bad word' when it is used to describe a person. Dog breeders use it for female dogs as a matter of course. Incidentally, _dog_ can also be an insulting term for a man ("You dirty dog!"), but people tend to make more effort to avoid _bitch_ because it is considered particularly offensive.

Comment: See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129301/polite-alternative-to-the-term-bitch-when-referring-to-a-female-dog?rq=1)

Comment: No one should be surprised that derogatory words for females of the species are applied to women:  not just 'bitch' but 'cow'.  'Bull' is flattering.  'dog' as in 'you old dog' is sort of admiring.  Similarly, calling a man an 'old goat' is sort of flattering, suggesting his continuing virility.  'Rat' and 'mouse' are gender neutral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bitch) is probably the best explanation, but the history is sketchy:

> bitch (n.)
>
> Old English bicce "female dog," probably from Old Norse bikkjuna
> "female of the dog" (also of the fox, wolf, and occasionally other
> beasts), which is of unknown origin. Grimm derives the Old Norse word
> from Lapp pittja, but OED notes that "the converse is equally
> possible." As a term of contempt applied to women, it dates from c.
> 1400; of a man, c. 1500, playfully, in the sense of "dog." Used among
> male homosexuals from 1930s. In modern (1990s, originally
> African-American vernacular) slang, its use with reference to a man is
> sexually contemptuous, from the "woman" insult.
>
> BITCH. A she dog, or doggess; the most offensive appellation that
> can be given
> to an English woman, even more provoking than that of
> whore. ["Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue," 1811]
>
> Bitch goddess coined 1906 by William James; the original one was
> success.
>
> bitch (v.)
>
> "to complain," attested from at least 1930, perhaps from the sense in
> bitchy, perhaps influenced by the verb meaning "to bungle, spoil,"
> which is recorded from 1823. But bitched in this sense seems to echo
> Middle English bicched "cursed, bad," a general term of opprobrium (as
> in Chaucer's bicched bones "unlucky dice"), which despite the
> hesitation of OED, seems to be a derivative of bitch (n.).

Comment: I wonder whether the opposite of a *doggess* isn’t a *dogger*.

Comment: A female fox is a vixen.